# Not able to filter the model using the Ember.Select in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The use case is I am trying to filter the model using the Ember.Select, whenever the user clicks the button, the model gets filtered on the basis of the 'Designation' property.

Here's my Ember.Select:

```
{{view Ember.Select
       contentBinding="designations"
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       optionLabelPath="content.designation"
       selectionBinding="roles.selectedDesignation"}}
<button {{action 'filter'}}>Filter</button>
```

And Here's what I am doing in App.js,

```
App.TwodController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    filteredContent : Ember.computed.oneWay("content"),
    selectedDesignation : null,
    designations : [{
        designation : "Design",
        id : 1
    }, {
        designation : "Writer",
        id : 2
    }],
    actions : {
        filter : function() {
            var designation = this.get('roles.selectedDesignation');
            var filtered = this.get('content').filterProperty('designation', designation);
            this.set("filteredContent", filtered);
        }
    }
});
```

Here's the full JSBin, http://jsbin.com/iPUxuJU/2/edit

What I might be missing here?

Comment: You missed to get `selectedDesignation.designation'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing something in selection binding

```
{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="designations"
   optionValuePath="content.id"
   optionLabelPath="content.designation"
   selectionBinding="selectedDesignation"}}
<button {{action 'filter'}}>Filter</button>
```

In controller logic:

```
App.TwodController = Ember.Controller.extend({
filteredContent : Ember.computed.oneWay("content"),
selectedDesignation : null,
designations : [{
    designation : "Design",
    id : 1
}, {
    designation : "Writer",
    id : 2
}],
actions : {
    filter : function() {
        var designation = this.get('selectedDesignation.designation');
        var filtered = this.get('content').filterProperty('designation', designation);
        this.set("filteredContent", filtered);
    }
}
```

});

Here is the working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eteweB/1#/twod)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, can you explain me a bit about the selection binding? I am think I may be confused.